# RabbitMQ Queue Max Priority Issue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

In rabbitMQ - Queue max priority

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-max-priority", 10);
Queue queue = new Queue("myQueue", true, false, false, args);
```

But when I am producing with message with priority 11, 10, 2. I am getting **message with priority 11 also**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Messages without a priority property are treated as if their priority
>   were 0. Messages with a priority which is higher than the queue's
>   maximum are treated as if they were published with the maximum
>   priority.

[Rabbit MQ priority reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)